# Resolve not accepting equations involving factorial

Tags: equation-solving

If I take ,

```
Resolve[ForAll[x,x!>=0],Integers]
True
```

But if I make slight modification,

```
Resolve[ForAll[x,x!>=x],Integers]

Resolve[Exists[x,x!>=x],Integers]
```

Then it is returned unevaluated. This also should be true. Using `Assuming` doesn't help either. I also failed to find any example on factorial in documentation on `Resolve`.
I have some equations involving factorials to be resolved but I am kind of stuck.
Can someone help ? I hope I am not making some subtle mistake in my attempt.

Comment: `{Resolve[ForAll[x, x > 1, x Log@x > Log@x], Reals], 
 Resolve[ForAll[x, x > 1, x^x > x], Reals]}`